# What is the use of mod_dav_svn.so?

Tags: apache, svn, tomcat, mod-dav-svn

While integrating the apache and the subversion, we are using mod_dav_svn.so and loading this module, can any one help me to know the use of this module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly speaking, it's a module which allows Apache HTTP Server to serve SVN repositories.

See WebDAV FAQ: ["What is mod_dav_svn and mod_dav_fs?"](http://www.webdav.org/mod_dav/faq/#00-04)

> **mod_dav_svn** is an interface for mod_dav that provides a CVS like
>   repository which is based on the new Delta-V specification. It is an
>   extension to WebDAV and useful if you need versioning control.

and [SVNBook | httpd, the Apache HTTP Server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.ref).